# Hide container div based on text of anchor url inside - with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a list of blog posts where the html has many nested divs that create the layout of it. I need to only hide the posts that contain a specific tag, so targeting the part of the url in the anchor that is `/tag/hidetag/`, then selecting then container class `post` of only those posts to be hidden, not all the other posts.

```html
<div class="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://mysite/mypost/">Title 1</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a href="http://mysite/tag/mytag/"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://mysite/mypost/">Title 2</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a href="http://mysite/tag/hidetag/"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use JS for this? It should really be done server side, as the content will still be sent to the client browser. Failing that, use CSS to avoid a FOUC: `.post:has(a[href$="tag/hidetag/"])`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh this is a great solution thank you! I did not know I could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't need JavaScript. All you need to do is find the `div`s with "post" class that `:has` `a` tag that contains "/tag/hidetag/":

```css
.post:has(a[href*="/tag/hidetag/"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://mysite/mypost/">Title 1</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a href="http://mysite/tag/mytag/"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://mysite/mypost/">Title 2</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <a href="http://mysite/tag/hidetag/"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```